# WS2016 ADS : Attribute value is not unique forest wide

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm getting this error in my Active directory server :

```
La valeur d’attribut fournie n’est pas unique dans la forêt ou la partition. Attribut : userPrincipalName Value=SERVER/administrateur@HOME.LAN
CN=JEEDOM,CN=Computers,DC=home,DC=lan Winerror : 8648 
Voir http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=279782 pour plus d’informations sur cette stratégie.
```

Anyway to fix this please ?

Thanx a lot !!

Comment: What are you trying to do when the message appears?

Comment: Nothing, it appears in the active directory window log, from the server manager, at periodic intervals...